# SAS : Make a crosswalk from values that change over time

Tags: sql, sas

I have a problem. I need to create a crosswalk for another table when an id changes itself in course of time. I need to have first year's id regardless of change in id.

```
data have;
input ORIG_ID $ CHANGE_ID $ YEAR
AAA  BBB  1990
BBB  AAA  1991
PPP  ZZZ  1993
ZZZ  YYY  1994
YYY  ZZZ  1996
TTT  MMM  1990
;

**What I want :**

 /****OUTPUT****/

CHANGE_ID ORIG_ID
BBB       AAA  
ZZZ       PPP
YYY       PPP
MMM       TTT
/*My logic so far*/
proc sql;
    create table temp as
    select CHANGE_ID, ORIG_ID
    case 
        when (CHANGE_ID<ORIG_ID) then cat(CHANGE_ID,ORIG_ID)
        when (ORIG_ID<CHANGE_ID) then cat(ORIG_ID,CHANGE_ID)
        end as key, year
    from dat
    order by key,year;
quit;

data final;
    retain CHANGE_ID ORIG_ID
    set temp;
    by key;
    if first.key;
run;
/*But this works for id changing for AAA to BBB, may be not*/
```

Let me know if you have any confusions :

Comment: I've never heard of a crosswalk in terms of data science or statistics. Are you talking about an audit trail to keep track of how ID values change?

Comment: hehe:). This crosswalk is needed for another dataset where we have id changes over time, sometimes id changes back to original and worst case ids keep changing. We want to keep all  changing ids to first one of occurrence.  Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hash object approach - it should work provided that

- You have enough memory to hold the whole input table
- You only have 1 change per ID per year, or
- Some way of ordering changes if there are multiple changes per ID per year

```
data have;
input ORIG_ID $ CHANGE_ID $ YEAR;
cards;
AAA  BBB  1990
BBB  AAA  1991
PPP  ZZZ  1993
ZZZ  YYY  1994
YYY  ZZZ  1996
TTT  MMM  1990
;
run;

proc sort data = have;
by CHANGE_ID descending YEAR;
run;

data v_have /view = v_have;
    set have;
    by CHANGE_ID;
    if first.CHANGE_ID then GRP = 0;
    GRP + 1;    
run;


data want;
  informat CHANGE_ID ORIG_ID;
  set v_have;
  /*Although we need the whole table in the hash, we only need to process each CHANGE_ID once*/
  by CHANGE_ID;
  if first.CHANGE_ID;

  /*Create a hash object to hold the table*/
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    dcl hash h(dataset:'v_have');
    rc = h.definekey('CHANGE_ID','GRP');
    rc = h.definedata('ORIG_ID','YEAR');
    rc = h.definedone();
  end;

  /*Make a temp copy of the starting ID*/
  T_CHANGE_ID = CHANGE_ID;
  PREV_YEAR = 2000;
  rc=0;

  /*Follow chains of IDs backwards through the table, making sure we only step backwards in time to avoid looping*/
  do while(rc = 0 and YEAR < PREV_YEAR);
    PREV_YEAR = YEAR;
    CHANGE_ID = ORIG_ID;
    /*If there are multiple records per CHANGE_ID, take the most recent one that's younger than the current record*/
    do GRP = 1 by 1 while(rc=0 and YEAR >= PREV_YEAR);
        rc = h.find();
    end;
  end;

  /*Output the last CHANGE_ID we got to plus the starting ID */
  ORIG_ID   = CHANGE_ID;  
  CHANGE_ID = T_CHANGE_ID;

  /*Ignore trivial rows resulting from cycles*/
  if CHANGE_ID ne ORIG_ID;
  keep CHANGE_ID ORIG_ID;
run;
```

Now a bit more complex but working properly. I might have a go at doing this using a multidata hash object as I think it's possible to eliminate the initial sort that way.

Comment: Thanks we're close, but above didn't give us desired output. Let us please keep in mind that the orig id should always the the id that occurred in first year. For me the input are alpha numeric and years are like 201201 201203 up-to 999912.

Comment: I've changed the algorithm so that it should now work with generic dates and produces the required output.

Comment: Thanks. Count me as a fan of yours. I'll still need some time to figure out how the algorithm does the magic.